# Set product visibility default value on "visible" (Catalog & Search)

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

When I edit a product on woocommerce I'd like to have the default settin woocommerce visibility options radio button, not "hidden" but "visible".

I tried to use add_filter to set default value on "visible" like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_visibility_options', 'set_visibility_default_visible', 10, 1);
function set_visibility_default_visible($array) {
    //set_catalog_visibility('visible');
    return 'visible';
}
```

but I miss all the other options:
Any suggest, thanks.

[product visibility default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Cdtb.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking, you wish the "Catalogue visibility" panel to be open by default when editing a product, so that you can see the form. You can do this by adding some css to admin ie

```
add_action('admin_head', 'show_catalog_visibility');
function show_catalog_visibility() {
  echo '<style>
    #catalog-visibility-select{
        display: block;
    }
  </style>';
}
```

The woocommerce_product_visibility_options filter is used to customise the actual options available not to determine if the panel is visible or not.

Edit : given the actual problem is that the product visibility for new products is defaulting to 'hidden' which is non standard

WooCommerce by default sets new product catalog visibility to 'visible'. If a new product is not starting out this way, it suggests that something eg a plugin is overriding the default value. Obviously it would always be best to identify the source of this behaviour if possible. In the worst case if the cause can't be found, the following code will set the default catalog visibility to 'visible' when a new product is created.

```
add_action('transition_post_status', 'jt_override_default_product_visibility', 10, 3);
function jt_override_default_product_visibility( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    if ( $old_status == 'new' && $new_status == 'auto-draft' && $post->post_type == 'product' ){
        $_product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );
        $_product->set_catalog_visibility('visible');
        $_product->save();
    }
}
```

Existing products visibility can be updated via a bulk edit from the product list page.

Comment: Thanks for reply @jtowell but I did not mean it. I try to explain better: when you edit a woocommerce product on the right column you can see the options about "Catalog visibility" (it is a radio button). For default the option "hidden" is set. I'd like to change that default setting on "visible" instead "hidden". Otherwise, before publish/update the product I've change that selection. I've tried the solution using add_filter and seems works, but I lost all the other options (see the image on my first post).

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding. I guess my issue is by default when you create a new product the value is "visible" ie "Shop & Search Results". Hence I am confused how your default is "hidden" unless you have something that is changing this value when new products are created eg some plugin. Are you seeing this default when creating a new product, or when editing one that has already been created?

Comment: No problem @jtowell. Seems only on edit the product is set on hidden.

Comment: I was wrong, this happen also in add a new product and on edit

Comment: @Marco this is very strange. I have updated my answer to suggest a way forward, though as I mention it would be more ideal to find the cause, as this seems unusual.